# Importar variables de entorno en windows desde fichero txt

Tags: windows, archivo, script, powershell, línea-de-comandos

Hola buenas tengo un archivo el txt el cual tiene una estructura similar a la siguiente:

```
PSWD=pswd
nombre=nombre
directorio=directorio
```

Existe algún comando o script en windows que me añada las distintas variables declaradas en el txt a las variables de entorno de mi sistema operativo windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer lograr eso debe descomponer tu problema en 2 partes:

- La primera en iterar dentro del archivo donde tienes tus variables
- Lo segundo ejecutar el comando para crear variables de entorno

Hice este script espero que te sirva (correlo en el directorio de tu archivo txt, y asumo que tienes los permisos para agregar variables de entorno):

```sh
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %a in (variables.txt) do setx %a "%b"
```

Lo que hace este script es recorrer tu archivo txt con las variables con el comando `for /f`, determina que el signo igual(=) es el delimitador y luego ejecuta `setx` comando encargado de crear variables de entorno, donde %a es el nombre de la variable y %b el valor. Para PSWD=pswd quedaria así `setx PSWD "pswd"`

Info sobre comando `setx` https://www.pantallazos.es/2019/03/microsoft-windows-cmd-crear-variables-entorno-setx.html

Info sobre `for /f` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for

Comment: Muchas gracias,me funcionó perfectamente y con la docu lo entendi todo.